# Send argparse help somewhere else

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a chatbot that uses commands parsed using `argparse`.

I'd like to keep the default `--help` behaviour, however I'd like to send that help somewhere other than `stdout`. Currently, when a user issues a command to the chatbot, it prints the help message to the terminal that it's running on (where the user can't see it), and then immediately crashes the script (which is to be expected).

Is there some way I can pipe the output text to some function other than `print`, (e.g. `self.reply`) and then not immediately exit the script?

If the only solution is to use `argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)` and then implement my own `--help` behaviour, is there some way I can extract the help text from argparse without needing to reimplement it? Can I be sure that `command --help` and `commmand --argument --help` will both work?

Comment: Look at `parser.print_help` and `parser.format_help`.  The default help is issued by a  'help action class' (look up the exact name), in its `__call__` method.